# Using image for text in retina and non retina screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I'm doing a book in which I display text with images in order to get the exact text layout I want.

The problem is that the text is crispy on non-retina display if I use retina images (image with *2 resolution). For the moment, I've added pages for retina and non-retina display but this means my application is bigger.

Is there a way to use only retina ressources and to have a nice text even on non-retina display ?

Comment: What control do you need over the text that you can't get with something like Core Text?

Comment: You could try using only retina-sized images, not call them @2x and scale them down yourself using CGAffineTransform. The scaled down images (non-retina) might look a bit blurry though.

Comment: @StephenDarlington My designer uses InDesign and work manually on the text in order to get the best layout possible. I really don't think we could get such good layout quality using core text and automatic layout.

Comment: @CedricSoubrie Why not export as a PDF? At least then the text would still be text, and would be rendered automatically to the right resolution.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't,:( since the non retina display is having less resolution screen compared to retina display thats why the concept of normal image and @2x image was introduced.
If you use UIImage's **imageNamed** property with your image it will automatically renders respective images wrt the devices,
ex:- if your image name is background.png and for retina display background@2x.png then once you write

```
   backgroundImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
```

it will automatically assigns normal & @2x image to non-retina & retina display.